# Handwritten digit image is unrecognizable after contouring and resizing

Tags: python, opencv, contour, image-recognition

I am using the following code to threshold a jpeg image -

```
image = cv.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/digit-recognition/hand-written-digits-1.jpg')
grey = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grey = cv.GaussianBlur(grey,(5,5),0)
# grey = cv.medianBlur(grey,5)
# thresh = cv.adaptiveThreshold(grey,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)
thresh = cv.adaptiveThreshold(grey,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV,7,2)
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# contours.sort(key=lambda x:get_contour_precedence(x, thresh.shape[1]))

plt.imshow(thresh, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
preprocessed_digits = []
for c in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(c)
    if w*h >= 130: 
        cv.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
        digit = thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        resized_digit = cv.resize(digit, (18,18))
        padded_digit = np.pad(resized_digit, ((5,5),(5,5)), "constant", constant_values=0)
        plt.imshow(padded_digit, cmap="gray")
        plt.show()
        xdigit = padded_digit.reshape(1,784)
        prediction = neigh.predict(xdigit)
        print("prediction = ",prediction[0])
```

This is the thresh image - 
[image]

This is the image of the digit 5 after contouring and resizing - 
[image]

If you notice in the thresh image the 5 appears properly. Whereas after contouring and resizing it appears improper and so gets predicted as 3. 
What could be the reason for this improper image or how can I fix it?

Comment: It would be interesting to see the "5" in the "thresh" image resized to the same size as the contoured image.   If the shapes of interest are always digits (characters) that look like "thresh", maybe a different approach like thresholding, gap filling, and skeletonizing might work.

Comment: @MarkLavin Yeah the shape of interest is always digits. When you mention different approaches like thresholding.. But I am using AdaptiveThresholding here isn't that the same. I will try the gap-filling and skeletonizing

Comment: Yes, whatever thresholding method proves best.

Comment: You should provide the original image. And use `cv2.imwrite(...` to save the processed images so that you can post without any grid/axis artifacts. The official docs have some great Python tutorials, including a section on [thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html). Adaptive thresholding shouldn't give you such a suboptimal result. Try to mess with the kernel size of your GaussianBlur. Also, you might look into Otsu thresholding.